# If elif with input() function

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a bot for an emulator, but before I implement the AI into it I wanted it to execute some commands which will be given in the console window. I made an if elif statement and inside of them I have defined the functions to interact with the emulator

```
if input() == 'Triple Jump':
    def triple_jump():
        print("Executing command", end="")
        for i in range(0, 5):
            print(".", end="")
            time.sleep(1)
        time.sleep(5)
        print(" ")
        print("Done")
        presskey(W_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        presskey(E_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        releasekey(E_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.6)
        presskey(E_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        releasekey(E_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.6)
        presskey(E_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        releasekey(E_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        releasekey(W_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        triple_jump()

elif input() == 'Walk':
    def walk():
        print("Executing command", end="")
        for i in range(0, 5):
            print(".", end="")
            time.sleep(1)
        time.sleep(5)
        print("")
        print("Done")
        presskey(W_KEY)
        time.sleep(2)
        releasekey(W_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.2)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        walk()

else:
    print("Could not execute command")
```

The problem is that if I enter "Walk", it won't do anything and if I press enter one or two more times, it will go to the else statement.

Comment: Input() returns immediately. so it can only be used in the place where you declare it. As you don't save the input but instead use input() again later, it will be a NEW input (hence the few extra returns you need to press)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
userValue = input("Enter your desired word: ")

if userValue == 'Triple Jump':
    def triple_jump():
        print("Executing command", end="")
        for i in range(0, 5):
            print(".", end="")
            time.sleep(1)
        time.sleep(5)
        print(" ")
        print("Done")
        presskey(W_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        presskey(E_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        releasekey(E_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.6)
        presskey(E_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        releasekey(E_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.6)
        presskey(E_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        releasekey(E_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        releasekey(W_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        triple_jump()

elif userValue == 'Walk':
    def walk():
        print("Executing command", end="")
        for i in range(0, 5):
            print(".", end="")
            time.sleep(1)
        time.sleep(5)
        print("")
        print("Done")
        presskey(W_KEY)
        time.sleep(2)
        releasekey(W_KEY)
        time.sleep(0.2)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        walk()

else:
    print("Could not execute command")
```

I don't have some of the libraries you are using but I could reach the elif statement

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately though when I do this it will just print the word that I assigned to "userValue", as a test I made a new py file to see if one of the libraries have an affect on ot but it didn't work. I assigned input("Triple Jump") to userValue1 and input("Walk") to userValue2 and put them in the code. Can you tell me if I did something wrong?

Comment: Why are you defining two userValues? You just need to define 1 userValue input and then let the script do the rest. Also `userValue1 = input("Triple Jump")` doesn't mean you are assigning it Triple Jump, this means on the console while taking the input from the user, it will print Triple Jump and expect the user to fill in his input. The string inside `input()` is an instruction, like I asked the user for `Enter your desired word: ` It will print that in the CL and you input your desired word against that.

Comment: Okay thank you very much. I finally got it to work.

Comment: I understand your sentiment behind it, but that wouldn't fix your issue, rather, that is not how it would work. because you can't expect the user to give two inputs unless absolutely necessary to your code. If you want to use both the inputs for the same purpose, then might as well define one input and iterate through if elif else loops. Try going through the code I answered above, I'm sure it will help you out

Comment: I went through it and thought about your comments and changed my code a little and now it works fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, remember to upvote and accept the answer :)